# Complete Haskore example

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know of a complete Haskore example that will take a small example and output a MIDI file? I'm looking for a starting point to start using Haskore and Google isn't turning up much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holy Moly! They sure don't make it easy do they?  Don't use the older, pre-2004 stuff (and it's often difficult to tell with no dates on wiki pages and no version numbers).

Does the cabal install work for you?
These examples worked for me:

http://code.haskell.org/haskore/revised/core/src/Haskore/Example/

Specifically, the Kantate147 writes a midi file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an extremely simple example for which works for me with the old [haskore-vintage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskore-vintage-0.1) package from 2000 (which [someone said was simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086463/next-steps-learning-haskell)):

```
import Haskore

n1 = Note (C, 4) 1 []
n2 = Note (F, 4) 1 []

ourChord = n1 :=: n2
ourMidiFile = testMidi ourChord
main = outputMidiFile "simple_example.mid" ourMidiFile
```