# next steps learning Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm not QUITE done with [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) tutorial. It's starting to get more "abstract" and I feel like I need to start some kind of Haskell project in order to solidify what I already know and see the things I've yet to learn in action (so they're more concrete and less theoretical). Problem is, I don't know what to work on. I've looked at HappStack - which looks AWESOME, but it also looks a little advanced. I was going through the "99 haskell problems" on haskell.org, but those are boring and I can't "show off" when I've completed them. Not that i'm just looking to show off, I just want something I can sort of "use".

Comment: Just a one-time thing, but you're probably at the stage where you will enjoy [20 intermediate haskell problems](http://blog.tmorris.net/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/). The point is to just try to write non-trivial implementations that still type-check. Turns out that you'll probably write correct instances; the classes represent actual (useful) classes.

Comment: If you want something that you can use, what do you need?  Web programming?  Lots of parsing/text munging?  Binary data?  Graphics?  At this stage you'll probably find a lot of application-domain stuff, so tell us what you're interested in.  Although I would recommend that you read the Typeclassopedia, http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf,  if you haven't yet.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at your suggestion, @Dan. As far as your question, @John, that's a problem I've always had in learning these kinds of things. I come from the school of people with CS degrees who didn't have a reason for building software FIRST. I always find that people who know WHY they want to program are better programmers than me. So when you ask "what do you need?" My answer is simply: to learn Haskell.

Comment: Having said all that, I've been toying with the idea of building myself a blog-type website. I don't really want to just use blogger or any of those canned blogs. I started with a Django tutorial, but now I'm intrigued about HappStack. So, I guess, I'm looking for a bridge between the early intermediate level of understanding I have now and becoming fluent with Happstack.

Comment: then how about FRP/Arrows via Yampa, or implementing a simple DSL?  Either will teach you a lot of Haskell, and both should be approachable after LYAH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a look at [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours).

Answer (score 5):

You might want to peruse some of the chapters in [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/), which gives some more practical/different applications of Haskell like [programming GUIs with GTK+ & Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/gui-programming-with-gtk-hs.html)

Plus, it's pretty good at complementing the material in [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If happstack is too much perhaps you should try some of the Hackage packages that are for teaching purposes?

- [Haskore-vintage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskore-vintage) is a simple version of haskore used in the classroom.
- [gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) provides high-level OpenGL-backed graphics used for instruction.

I'm not feeling very creative right now, but am leaving this as a wiki - if you're interested in this venue then comment and perhaps others will add to the list.

Comment: haskore-vintage looks very interesting. checking that out now.